# Debugging Techniques in JavaScript. Async Callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, asynchronous, coffeescript

In an existing Backbone/jQuery/CoffeeScript app I am working on, it appears there is a function (`Backbone.Collection.fetch()`) called multiple times (sometimes number may vary). I think it might be a timing thing as I am doing alot of nested callbacks (like AJAX etc) and its becoming hard to debug. I should probably try to convert the code to use jQuery deferred but in the mean time, what can I do?

Just tried walking through the code in Chrome, but it appears the code is jumping here and there, maybe its processing different callbacks at the same time?

I am thinking maybe I add a console.log to every function + its arguments, but there must be a better way?

Comment: Have you tried using Firefox and Firebug?  In some ways Firebug is superior to what Chrome offers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a stack trace to that `fetch()` function, and see where it's being called from.  There are a number of decent stack trace implementations for JS.  I've had good success with 
[Eric Wendelin's version](https://github.com/eriwen/javascript-stacktrace), but there are [plenty of others](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+stack+trace).

With the stack trace, perhaps you can at least see what the most common paths are into that function, and that might help narrow down where to search.  It might even make clear the underlying culprit.

Comment: Just add `debugger;` inside the function code. That will cause the inspector to pause at that point.

Comment: It sounded as though there were too many calls to simply debug.  A number of stacks that could be analyzed might tell something that couldn't be seen through a debugger.